# How to get AWS Lex conversation history for particular user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

Is there any way to get AWS Lex conversation history for particular user or otherwise do we need to save the conversation to DB user wise.

If we can get the conversation history then we can create continues conversation flow in our website

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, though you would need to enable the Cloudwatch logs for your Lex bot.
You can then query the logs using the log insights in CW and the correct query.
As an example, you could use this query to bring back the inputs for a particular user: -

```
FIELDS inputTranscript
| filter userId like '965d8ec2-6c7a-24b2-53c2-a3ae1b5af9ac'
| sort Requests desc
| limit 10
```

Have a read through [this article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mt/analyzing-amazon-lex-conversation-log-data-amazon-cloudwatch-insights/).

Comment: Thank you so much @Reegz. I'll try and give the feedback.